# Free algebra of nonassociative words

Tags: abstract-algebra

First of all, sorry for my grammar, English is not my first language. Now, I'm reading Drensky's Free algebra and PI-algebras and I came across with the next  [definition.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ymcky.jpg)

> Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a class of algebras and let $F\in \mathcal{B}$ be an algebra generated by a set $X.$ The algebra $F$ is called a *free algebra in the class $\mathcal{B}$, freely generated by the set $X$,* if for any algebra $R\in\mathcal{B},$ every mapping $X\rightarrow R$ can be extended to a homomorphism $F\rightarrow R.$ The cardinality $|X|$ of the set $X$ is called the *rank* of $F.$

Now, let's assume $K$ is a field and every algebra or vector space is over $K$, there is an exercise next:

> Let $K\{X\}$ be the vector space with basis the set of all nonassociative words, i.e. words of the form $$(x_{i_1}\dots)(\dots x_{i_n}),$$ $x_{i_k}\in X,$ where the parentheses are distributed in an arbitrary way. The multiplication in $K\{X\}$ is given by $u\cdot v =(u)(v)$ for any two words $u,v.$ (More precisely, we omit the extra parentheses and, for example, write $x_i\cdot x_j=x_ix_j$ instead of $(x_i)(x_j),$ $x_i \cdot u=x_i(u)$ instead of $(x_i)(u),$ etc.) Show that this algebra is free in the class of all unitary algebras.

I think they say $K\{X\}$ is an unitary algebra with the unity the empty word. I am going to write my take on this, to see if it is correct because I feel what I did is just not good enough.

First, we have to find a set that generates $K\{X\}$ as an algebra, and $X$ is our candidate. Let $\varphi: X\rightarrow A$ a map, where $A$ is an unitary algebra. We can define $\bar{\varphi}: K\{X\}\rightarrow A$ an unitary algebra homomorphism such that is induced by $\varphi,$ that means $\bar{\varphi}(1)=1_A$ and $$\bar{\varphi}((x_{j_1}\dots)(\dots x_{j_m})+(x_{i_1}\dots)(\dots x_{i_n}))=(\varphi(x_{j_1})\dots)(\dots\varphi(x_{j_m}))+(\varphi(x_{i_1})\dots)(\dots\varphi(x_{i_n}))$$

Since $\varphi$ and $A$ were arbitrary, we are done.

I'm not sure if I'm omitting a step or if I can define $\bar{\varphi}$ like that, but I don't think there is any trouble doing so. If there is something I'm missing or doing wrong I will appreciate a lot if you guys would tell me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks good to me (but you haven't proved that $\bar{\phi}$ is a $k$-algebra homomorphism, some people would say it is ``obvious", but if it isn't to you you should prove it).

Altogether I think it could be expressed in a clearer way. For example, we know that as a $k$-vector space we have
$$K\{X\} = \bigoplus_{w \in W} k \cdot w$$
where $W$ is the set of all words in the elements of $X$. Therefore, to specify a $k$-linear map out of $K\{X\}$ we just need to specify where each word $w$ goes, which I think is what you are getting at in your line
$$\bar{\phi}(x_{j_1} \cdots \ \ \ \ etc).$$
Of course once you have such a $k$-linear map you need to prove it is actually a $k$-algebra homomorphism, which requires some work depending on how careful you want to be.

Please let me know if you have further questions. I can translate this to Spanish too.

Comment: This is great. I was trying to figure out a way to make it look more... polished, and you just provided it! Thank you.